# Is it possible to have Wine use a dual-boot Windows's profile data and vice versa?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, wine, user-profile

I'm still only learning Ubuntu but I've already found out that for 99% of my purposes it works much better than Windows, especially considering how robust Wine has become.

For that potential missing 1% however, I'd like to have a Windows 7 (or another version) installation alongside my Xubuntu. My question is this: is it possible for Wine to use the Windows' profile's appdata, registry, user folders, and so on? Respectively, is it possible for changes made to those files using Windows be used by Wine?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have Wine use a dual-boot Windows's profile data and vice versa?

No.

> Respectively, is it possible for changes made to those files using Windows be used by Wine?

No.

WINE is not a drop-in replacement for Windows.

Why are you skipping the more obvious method: virtualbox/vmware virtualization. Internally that would be 100% identical to a normal installed Windows. Only thing that is required is to set up guest additions to have Windows be able to connect to external devices.

Comment: Could you elaborate why it's not possible? As far as I know, Wine works with exactly the same registry format and supports setting up Windows-style User profiles in exactly the same configuration as Windows proper. As for virtualbox, my concern is that I mostly work with GPU-intensive software and (apologies if I'm misinformed) Virtualbox doesn't support GPU acceleration at all beyond the most basic functionality.

Comment: WINE has its own internal implementation that mimics windows but it is not the same and is not interchangeable. GPU: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d is the best you can get.